# How can I sort a list of IP-addresses in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, ipv4

I have a bunch of IP-addresses stored in an array, e.g.:

```
my @ip = qw(10.11.1.1 10.100.1.1 ...);
```

How can I sort the addresses in the ascending order? I've tried a simple `sort` but it failed, of course.

Comment: How do you want to sort it? As 32-bits integers? As strings? By component?

Comment: All good questions from WTP -- see also, what do you mean "failed"? How do you think they should sort?

Answer (score 12):

IPv4 addresses are just 32-bit numbers.

```
use Socket qw( inet_aton );
my @sorted =
    map substr($_, 4),
       sort
          map inet_aton($_) . $_,
             @ips;
```

or

```
my @sorted =
    map substr($_, 4),
       sort
          map pack('C4a*', split(/\./), $_),
             @ips;
```

The first one also accepts domain names.

Comment: Ironically, I didn't use the IP addresses in their numerical form, but as packed numbers. To get an IPv4 address as a number, use `unpack 'N'` on the result of `inet_aton($_)` or `pack('C4', split(/\./, $_))`.

Comment: @ysth, Thanks. I figure if it's worth doing with ST, it's worth doing with GRT (although I can never remember what it's called).

Comment: Nice solution, but it took me a few moments to figure out how it actually works. I added an answer here that contains my notes, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not fond of any solution that assumes more that it needs. I've been burned on this sort of thing by compact notation before, and I imagine this problem gets tougher when IPv6 becomes more common. I'd just let [Net::IP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IP) figure it out:

```
use 5.010;
use Net::IP;

my @ip = qw(
    192.168.1.10
    172.16.5.5
    256.0.0.1
    192.168.1/24
    127.1
    127.0.1
    fd00:6587:52d7:f8f7:5a55:caff:fef5:af31
    fd24:cd9b:f001:884c:5a55:caff:fef5:af31 
    );

my @sorted = 
    map  { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map  { [ $_, eval { Net::IP->new( $_ )->intip } ] }
    @ip;

say join "\n", @sorted;
```

This handles the compact and range notations just fine and the `eval` catches the bad IP addresses. I don't have to treat IPv4 and IPv6 separately:

```
256.0.0.1
127.0.1
127.1
172.16.5.5
192.168.1/24
192.168.1.10
fd00:6587:52d7:f8f7:5a55:caff:fef5:af31
fd24:cd9b:f001:884c:5a55:caff:fef5:af31
```

Comment: the eval may catch exceptions from bad IP addresses but then leaves you comparing undef, giving warnings

Comment: Except this doesn't correctly sort mixed collections of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. (For example, `192.168.1.10 ::ffff:192.168.1.11 192.168.1.12` aren't returned in that order.) It also accepts a lot more than IP addresses (though that may not be an issue), but not domain names.

Answer (score 2):

use [Sort::Key::IPv4](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort%3a%3aKey%3a%3aIPv4)

Comment: This doesn't handle compact notation.

Comment: @brian d foy: do you mean IPv6 compact notation? obviously the module does not support IPv6, it has "IPv4" in its name for something!

Comment: Nope, I mean the IPv4 compact notation.

Comment: On May 21, 2012 v0.03, author added support for CIDR (aka 'compact') notation. https://metacpan.org/dist/Sort-Key-IPv4/changes so network addresses like 10.2.4.0/24 will now work.

Answer (score 1):

Just IPv4 addresses?

```
my @ip = map $_->[0],
    sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
    map [ $_, join '', map chr, split /\./, $_ ],
    qw( 10.1.2.3 172.20.1.2 192.168.1.2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking @ikegami's answer which turned out to work perfectly, but I had no clue why. So I took couple moments to figure out the mechanics behind it and I want to share my notes for future reference for the lesser Perl experts ...

In this example I chose two very specific IP addresses because when encoded as ASCII they'll look like `ABCD` and `EFGH`, as seen by the output of the `print Dumper()` line.

The trick is to prefix every IP-address string with 4 bytes containing its binary representation. Then the entries are sorted and finally the prefix is removed again, leaving a list of sorted IP-addresses.

The inner workings are described in the comments, best to read them in the numbered order.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @ips = qw( 69.70.71.72 65.66.67.68 );

print Dumper( map( pack( 'C4a*' , split( /\./ ) , $_ ) , @ips ) );

foreach my $ip (
  map(                            # 5. For each IP address that was enriched with 32 bits representation ....
    substr( $_ , 4) ,             # 6. Snip off the first four bytes as this is just a binary representation of the string, used for sorting.
    sort(                         # 4. Sort will essentially work on the first 4 octets as these will represent the entire remainder of the string.
      map(                        # 1. For each IP address in @ARGV ...
        pack( 'C4a*' ,            # 3. Change ASCII encoded octets from the IP address into a 32 bit 'string' (that can be sorted) and append it with the original IP address string for later use.
          split( /\./ ), $_ ) ,   # 2. Split the IP address in separate octets
        @ips                      # 0. Unsorted list of IP addresses.
      )    
    )
  )
) {
    print "$ip\n";
}
```

The output will look as follows:

```
$VAR1 = 'EFGH69.70.71.72';
$VAR2 = 'ABCD64.65.66.67';
64.65.66.67
69.70.71.72
```

Where the first two lines are from `print Dumper()` which shows the IP- addresses are prefixed with a 32-bit representation of the numeric IP-addresses.

Comment: Anyone feel free to improve the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4 filename  

or | to sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4
```

and you can reverse it... -r  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a good start:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub Compare {
    # TODO: Error checking
    my @a  = split /\./, $a;
    my @b = split /\./, $b;
    # TODO: This might be cleaner as a loop
    return $a[0] <=> $b[0] ||
           $a[1] <=> $b[1] ||
           $a[2] <=> $b[2] ||
           $a[3] <=> $b[3];
}

my @ip = qw( 172.20.1.2 10.10.2.3 10.1.2.3 192.168.1.2 );

@ip = sort Compare @ip;

print join("\n", @ip), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a module designed to [sort software version numbers](http://search.cpan.org/~edavis/Sort-Versions-1.5/Versions.pm). Maybe that will do what you want?